# No input validation message in Opera

Tags: html, validation, opera, email-validation

Enter not valid email address or some text, press OK - Opera 22 does not display any validation error message and form isn't submitting... Is this an Opera bug or I'm doing something wrong?

```
<form>
  <input type="email"/>
  <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

Test here: [http://jsfiddle.net/sPUEG](http://jsfiddle.net/sPUEG/)

Answer (score 0):

Define what you mean by `not valid` e-mail, there is pretty counter intuitive regex pattern for e-mail validation, according RFC 5321 and RFC 5322.

**Syntax**

The format of email addresses is `local-part@domain` where the `local-part` may be up to 64 characters long and the `domain` name may have a maximum of 253 characters – but the maximum of 256-character length of a forward or reverse path restricts the entire email address to be no more than 254 characters long.

The formal definitions are in RFC 5322 (sections 3.2.3 and 3.4.1) and RFC 5321 – with a more readable form given in the informational RFC 3696[3] and the associated errata.

**Local part**

The `local-part` of the email address may use any of these `ASCII` characters. RFC 6531 permits Unicode characters beyond the ASCII range:

- Uppercase and lowercase English letters (a–z, A–Z) (ASCII: 65–90, 97–122)
- Digits 0 to 9 (ASCII: 48–57)
- These special characters: ! # $ % & ' * + - / = ? ^ _ ` { | } ~ (limited support)
- Character . (dot, period, full stop) (ASCII: 46) provided that it is not the first or last character, and provided also that it does not appear two or more times consecutively (e.g. John..Doe@example.com is not allowed).
- Special characters are allowed with restrictions. They are:
- Space and "(),:;<>@[] (ASCII: 32, 34, 40, 41, 44, 58, 59, 60, 62, 64, 91–93)
- The restrictions for special characters are that they **must only be used** when contained between quotation marks, and that 2 of them (the backslash \ and quotation mark " (ASCII: 92, 34)) must also be preceded by a backslash \ (e.g. "\\"").
- Comments are allowed with parentheses at either end of the local part; e.g. `john.smith(comment)@example.com` and `(comment)john.smith@example.com` are both equivalent to `john.smith@example.com`.
- International characters above U+007F are permitted by RFC 6531, though mail systems may restrict which characters to use when assigning local parts.

A quoted string may exist as a dot separated entity within the local-part, or it may exist when the outermost quotes are the outermost characters of the local-part (e.g. `abc."defghi".xyz@example.com` or `"abcdefghixyz"@example.com` **are allowed**. Conversely, `abc"defghi"xyz@example.com` is not; neither is `abc\"def\"ghi@example.com`).

Quoted strings and characters however, are not commonly used. RFC 5321 also warns that "*a host that expects to receive mail SHOULD avoid defining mailboxes where the Local-part requires (or uses) the Quoted-string form*".

The `local-part` postmaster is treated specially–it is case-insensitive, and should be forwarded to the domain email administrator. Technically all other `local-parts` are case-sensitive, therefore `jsmith@example.com` and `JSmith@example.com` specify different mailboxes; however, many organizations treat uppercase and lowercase letters as equivalent.

Most organizations do not allow use of many of the technically valid special characters. Organizations are free to restrict the forms of their own email addresses as desired, e.g., Windows Live Hotmail, for example, only allows creation of email addresses using alphanumerics, dot (.), underscore (_) and hyphen (-).[5]

Systems that send mail must be capable of handling outgoing mail for all valid addresses. Contrary to the relevant standards, some defective systems treat certain legitimate addresses as invalid and fail to handle mail to these addresses. Hotmail, for example, refuses to send mail to any address containing any of the following standards-permissible characters: `!#$%*/?^`{|}~`.

**Domain part**

The domain name part of an email address has to conform to strict guidelines: it must match the requirements for a `hostname`, consisting of **letters, digits, hyphens and dots**. In addition, the domain part may be an **IP address literal**, surrounded by square braces, such as `jsmith@[192.168.2.1]`, although this is **rarely** seen except in email spam.

Internationalized domain names (which are encoded to comply with the requirements for a hostname) **allow for presentation** of non-ASCII domain parts.

Comments are allowed in the domain part as well as in the local part. E.g. `john.smith@(comment)example.com` and `john.smith@example.com(comment)` are equivalent to `john.smith@example.com`.

**Examples**

*Valid email addresses*

`niceandsimple@example.com`

`very.common@example.com`

`a.little.lengthy.but.fine@dept.example.com`

`disposable.style.email.with+symbol@example.com`

`other.email-with-dash@example.com`

*Invalid email addresses*

`Abc.example.com` (an @ character must separate the local and domain parts)

`A@b@c@example.com` (only one @ is allowed outside quotation marks)

`a"b(c)d,e:f;g<h>i[j\k]l@example.com` (none of the special characters in this local part is allowed outside quotation marks)

`just"not"right@example.com` (quoted strings must be dot separated, or the only element making up the local-part)

`this is"not\allowed@example.com` (spaces, quotes, and backslashes may only exist when within quoted strings and preceded by a backslash)

`this\ still\"not\\allowed@example.com` (even if escaped (preceded by a backslash), spaces, quotes, and backslashes must still be contained by quotes)

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address) for details.